# Hibernate StoredProcedure with joins and Temporary table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a MySQL StoredProcedure(EmployeeAbsentReport Procedure)for Given Two Dateranges. which is Successfully running on MySql Commandprompt.
How can I run this Stored Procedure using Hibernate,I found one Example on How to call Stored Procedure [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate),But in the Example program
he worked with a single table.

Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AbsentReportproc`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AbsentReportproc`(IN _fromdate DATETIME, IN _todate DATETIME)
BEGIN 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE daterange25 (dte DATE); 

    SET @counter := 0;
    WHILE (@counter < DATEDIFF(DATE(_todate), DATE(_fromdate))) DO 
        INSERT INTO daterange25 VALUES (DATE_ADD(_fromdate, INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 DAY));
    END WHILE;

SELECT tp.EMPCODE,tp.NAME,tp.DEPARTMENT, Group_Concat(d.dte order by d.dte SEPARATOR '\n')AbsentDate, COUNT(tp.EMPCODE) Totalnoofabsentdates
FROM Master tp
JOIN daterange25 d
LEFT JOIN Transactions tpt ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode) AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL
GROUP BY tp.EMPCODE;   

    DROP TABLE daterange25;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

how to call a Stored Procedure using Hibernate with joins(Including a Temporary Table)and writing sql-query in XML mapping file?

Answer (score 0):

Following the common framework method which i have used in one of my project to call the Stored Procedure of MySQL database :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public <T> List<T> executeSP(final String spName,
            final String[] parameterNames, final String[] parameterValues,
            final String[] resultColumnNames, final int offset, final int size,
            final Class<T> returnType) {
        validateParams(parameterNames, parameterValues);
        return (List<T>) hibernateTemplate
                .execute(new HibernateCallback<List<T>>() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public List<T> doInHibernate(final Session session) {
                        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("call "
                                + spName);
                        if (returnType != null) {
                            query.addEntity(returnType);
                        }
                        setQueryParams(parameterNames, parameterValues, query);
                        setResultColumnNames(resultColumnNames, query);
                        if (offset >= 0) {
                            query.setFirstResult(offset);
                        }
                        if (size > 0) {
                            query.setMaxResults(size);
                        }
                        return query.list();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Next, i would suggest that please make the Temporary Table join into the Stored Procedure only, instead of make it join with SP, if execute in SP then it is better from performance point of view also.

Comment: I'm new to Hibernate Could you Provide me the HibernateMapping File Here?

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not have xml mapping, have used annotation based entity objects.